# Custom Config File Parsing in Bash

Tags: parsing, bash

I'm creating a bash script for *screen* management and want to pull variables from a config file formatted like so:

```
[s=sample1]
FOLDER=folder/right/here
COMMAND=python script.py

[i=irssi]
COMMAND=irssi
BOOT
```

`"FOLDER"`, `"COMMAND"`, and `"BOOT"` would be optional. `"[x=y]"` would be required, where `"x"` is a single lowercase letter.

I'd like for this sample to be parsed into something like:

```
NAME[0]="sample1"
SHORT[0]="s"
FOLDER[0]="folder/right/here"
COMMAND[0]="python script.py"

NAME[1]="irssi"
SHORT[1]="i"
BOOT[1]="1"
```

Comment: Why design a config file syntax that is very difficult to parse? Why not just set the relevant bash variables and source it?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need to parse ini-styled config files in bash, have a look at this [link](http://ajdiaz.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/bash-ini-parser/). Else, as others have pointed out, just place the variables in a file and source it...

Comment: I've previously just been sourcing variables but the reason I'm here is because people who are using my script have been asking for something easier to use. The potential code for this I could also hack later for other projects.